# How to check if theres a page added to a server via PHP?

Tags: php, apache, indexing

I want to create a script that checks for a new post on a blogs server like gizmodo or something. Is there a php function that can do this? or anyway at all?

Comment: check out their api.  Its not obvious from your question what function you are wishing to use?

Comment: you mean like an rrs feed reader?

Comment: theres one included in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use RSS. RSS is XML. PHP can parse this. There are many PHP examples and "scripts" on the interwebs. Have a search around for PHP RSS reader and use one that you can understand.

Of course the blog you want to check must have an RSS feed. Most blogs have an RSS feed or something similar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_feed_aggregators